# load jquery and declare function at body onload

Tags: jquery, onload, document-ready

I'm quite new with JQuery (and not so good in javascript as well) and sometimes I've problems with syntax.

Here is the actual code I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/functions/jquery.lightbox-0.5.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('a.lightbox').lightBox(); // Select all links with lightbox class
    });
</script>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/functions/bannerRotator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        bannerRotator('#bannerRotator', 800, 4000);
    });
</script>
```

What I'm trying to do is to load the 3 javascript files after the body is loaded and then declare the 2 function (lightbox and bannerRotator).

I could make it to work by loading JQuery in the head of the page and then use $(document).ready to load scripts and declare functions, what I don't know how to do is make the jQuery library load after the full page is loaded then load the scripts and declare functions.

Unfortunately I've tried many things and none worked. If I can dynamically load the js scripts after body is loaded, I don't know how to declare the jQuery functions.

Hope somebody can help me with this.

Thank you for help.

Seems my request wasn't clear enough.

What I'm looking for:

```
<body onload="javascript:includeLibraries();">
</body>
...
function includeLibraries(){
    //load jquery
    //load lightbox
    //declare lightbox function
    //load bannerRotator.js
    //execute bannerRotator function
}
```

Want to do this after page is loaded and shown to site's visitor.

Comment: first you missed close tag for lightbox script

Comment: First load your jQuery, then your libraries, and then put everything in a doc ready.

Comment: @Bram, my question is actually how to do so when body onload is fired.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/functions/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/functions/jquery.lightbox-0.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/functions/bannerRotator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('a.lightbox').lightBox(); // Select all links with lightbox class
    bannerRotator('#bannerRotator', 800, 4000);
  });
</script>
```

Try this. Note that you are loading [a very out-dated version of jQuery](https://code.jquery.com/).

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer.I know how to do so, but how to do after body is loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be going something like this.

Load scripts:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/functions/jquery.lightbox-0.5.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/functions/bannerRotator.js"></script>
```

Call jquery functions:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('a.lightbox').lightBox(); // Select all links with lightbox class
    bannerRotator('#bannerRotator', 800, 4000);
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer.I know how to do so, but how to do after body is loaded ?

Comment: jQuery documentation: 
A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside $( document ).ready() will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside $( window ).load(function() { ... }) will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ . So to make it understandable for everybody - if code is inside .ready() function then it gets loaded after everything else